# Extending Django admin delete confirmation page

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

I am wondering if it is possible to extend Django Admin's delete confirmation page  for specific app and model. I want the functionality that enable user  to delete all records like that of django admin interface. it is possible to extends delete confirmation.html in my app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the Django admin delete confirmation page. To extend it, in your templates directory, create a directory named `admin` and create an html file named `delete_selected_confirmation.html` with the below content ([the default admin delete confirmation page source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/delete_selected_confirmation.html))

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load i18n l10n admin_urls static %}

{% block extrahead %}
    {{ block.super }}
    {{ media }}
    <script src="{% static 'admin/js/cancel.js' %}" async></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block bodyclass %}{{ block.super }} app-{{ opts.app_label }} model-{{ opts.model_name }} delete-confirmation delete-selected-confirmation{% endblock %}

{% block breadcrumbs %}
<div class="breadcrumbs">
<a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{% translate 'Home' %}</a>
&rsaquo; <a href="{% url 'admin:app_list' app_label=opts.app_label %}">{{ opts.app_config.verbose_name }}</a>
&rsaquo; <a href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'changelist' %}">{{ opts.verbose_name_plural|capfirst }}</a>
&rsaquo; {% translate 'Delete multiple objects' %}
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% if perms_lacking %}
    <p>{% blocktranslate %}Deleting the selected {{ objects_name }} would result in deleting related objects, but your account doesn't have permission to delete the following types of objects:{% endblocktranslate %}</p>
    <ul>
    {% for obj in perms_lacking %}
        <li>{{ obj }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% elif protected %}
    <p>{% blocktranslate %}Deleting the selected {{ objects_name }} would require deleting the following protected related objects:{% endblocktranslate %}</p>
    <ul>
    {% for obj in protected %}
        <li>{{ obj }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>{% blocktranslate %}Are you sure you want to delete the selected {{ objects_name }}? All of the following objects and their related items will be deleted:{% endblocktranslate %}</p>
    {% include "admin/includes/object_delete_summary.html" %}
    <h2>{% translate "Objects" %}</h2>
    {% for deletable_object in deletable_objects %}
        <ul>{{ deletable_object|unordered_list }}</ul>
    {% endfor %}
    <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <div>
    {% for obj in queryset %}
    <input type="hidden" name="{{ action_checkbox_name }}" value="{{ obj.pk|unlocalize }}">
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete_selected">
    <input type="hidden" name="post" value="yes">
    <input type="submit" value="{% translate 'Yes, I’m sure' %}">
    <a href="#" class="button cancel-link">{% translate "No, take me back" %}</a>
    </div>
    </form>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

now the directory and file structure should look like this. Now you can extend the above template as per your need.

```
├── templates
    └──  admin
        └── delete_selected_confirmation.html
```